# How can i access active screen time of IOS in react native?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, healthkit

[Want to access the total awake time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Kwuq.png)

Is there any specific way to access the screen time on ios from react-native.?

Comment: It would be helpful if you described what you have tried so far and what documentation you have looked at.

Comment: I saw apple community's comment over this topic, from 2 years ago.
And there was no update about if they have shared the API for accessing the screen time of apple IOS.

Many have searched and asked for it.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/103745